# Do I need to use "bigMod algorithm" in python?

Tags: python

As python don't have any limitation in storing numbers like c or c++, do I need to apply the bigMod algorithm? My this bit of code can handle the situation pretty smoothly.

```
number1 = 523523523523523523523523523523523523
number2 = 123
mod = 5

print(pow(number1, number2) % mod)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `pow()` can be used in this way:

```
number1 = 523523523523523523523523523523523523
number2 = 123
mod = 5

print(pow(number1, number2, mod))
```

It is already optimized and will be much faster.

you can read more about it in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow).

Answer (score 0):

According to Python documentation, Python 3 (not 2) integers are of [unlimited size](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) and there is no disclaimer regarding module or pow (see table).
So I wouldn't apply a bigMod algorithm.

You can read about it in this fine [blog](https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/)